# SwiftUI - Dynamically filter and fetch CoreData records via attributes

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have records saved in my data model but I was wondering how I could filter & fetch data dynamically in accordance to parameters I pass in, for example, my data model is of type people which includes their name, age and occupation.

Let's say I wish to return 20 records, but each record can slightly vary. These are my parameters, they are static:

```
let ageParamters = [60, 24, 35, 64, 29, 39, 90, 92, 38, 48, 23, 58, 62, 78, 19, 18, 29, 48, 40]
```

I wish to get a single record for a person for who's age matches the current index of the array, so first person will be aged 60, the next 24, 35 after that and so forth.

But extending on that, how could I filter my data by observing two fields such as the age and occupation like so:

```
let ageOccupationParamters = [[20: "Doctor"], [78: "Retired"], [32: "Police"]]
```

I'd appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many Core Data tutorials that show what you want. This is not a place to get a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample, it comes down to 2 basic ways.

The iOS 15+ way and the pre-iOS 15 way.

They both use `NSPredicate` (single criteria) or `NSCompoundPredicate` (multiple criteria).

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct FilteredListView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: FilteredListViewModel = .init()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Person.age, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var people: FetchedResults<Person>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                FilterOptionsView(fromAge: $vm.fromAge, toAge: $vm.toAge, selectedOccupation: $vm.occupation, occupations: vm.uniqueOccupations)
                HStack{
                    //This is the iOS 15+ way
                    SimpleListView(label: "@FetchRequest", people: Array(people))
                        .onChange(of: vm.toAge, perform: { val in
                            ///This can only be used on iOS15+
                            setThePredicate()
                        })
                        .onChange(of: vm.fromAge, perform: { val in
                            ///This can only be used on iOS15+
                            setThePredicate()
                        })
                        .onChange(of: vm.occupation, perform: { val in
                            ///This can only be used on iOS15+
                            setThePredicate()
                        })
                    //This is the other os compatible version but it does not observe the store
                    SimpleListView(label: "NSFetchRequest", people: Array(vm.people))
                }
            }.toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing, content: {
                    Button("add samples", action: {
                        vm.addSamples()
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    }
    ///This can only be used on iOS15+
    func setThePredicate(){
        //You can use any of the predicates I created in the extension here
        people.nsPredicate = Person.ageAndOccupationPredicate(ageFrom: Int16(vm.fromAge), ageTo: Int16(vm.toAge), occupation: vm.occupation)
    }
}
class FilteredListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var fromAge: Int = 14{
        didSet{
            //Update the list when the variable changes
            getNewList()
        }
    }
    @Published var toAge: Int = 100{
        didSet{
            //Update the list when the variable changes
            getNewList()
        }
    }
    @Published var occupation: String = ""{
        didSet{
            //Update the list when the variable changes
            getNewList()
        }
    }
    @Published var people: [Person] = []
    
    var uniqueOccupations: [String]{
        ///Get all the items, get the unique values of the occupations with the set, and then get the array for the View
        Array(Set(getObjects(nsPredicate:  nil).map{$0.occupation ?? "unknown"}))
    }
    
    func addSamples(){
        for _ in 0...20{
            let context = PersistenceController.previewAware.container.viewContext
            _ = Person(context: context)
        }
    }
    //Other os version way of using the predicate
    func getNewList(){
        //This is retrieved using NSFetchRequest it does not observe the store
        //Any tutorial will show you how to make this request
        people = getObjects(nsPredicate:  Person.ageAndOccupationPredicate(ageFrom: Int16(fromAge), ageTo: Int16(toAge), occupation: occupation))
    }
    
    func getObjects(nsPredicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> [Person]{
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
        request.predicate = nsPredicate
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Person.age, ascending: true)]
        
        do{
            let context = PersistenceController.previewAware.container.viewContext
            return try context.fetch(request)
        }catch{
            print(error)
            return []
        }
    }
}
struct SimpleListView: View{
    let label: String
    var people: [Person]
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(label)
            List(people, id: \.objectID) { person in
                HStack{
                    Text(person.age.description)
                    Text(person.occupation ?? "no occupation")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct FilterOptionsView: View{
    @Binding var fromAge:Int
    @Binding var toAge:Int
    @Binding var selectedOccupation: String
    var occupations: [String]
    var body: some View{
        Slider(value: Binding(get: {
            //Return the fromAge
            Double(fromAge)
        }, set: { val in
            //If the ages will overlap don't update the variables
            if val < Double(toAge){
                fromAge = Int(val)
            }
        }), in: 14...100, label: {
            Text("from")
        })
        Slider(value: Binding(get: {
            //Return the toAge
            Double(toAge)
        }, set: {val in
            //If the ages will overlap don't update the variables
            if val > Double(fromAge){
                toAge = Int(val)
            }
        }), in: 14...100, label: {
            Text("to")
        })
        Picker("occupations", selection: $selectedOccupation, content: {
            ForEach(occupations, id: \.self){ occ in
                Text(occ).tag(occ)
            }
            Text("all occupations").tag("")
        })
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct FilteredListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FilteredListView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.previewAware.container.viewContext)
    }
}

extension Person{
    public override func awakeFromInsert() {
        self.age = Int16.random(in: 16...100)
        self.occupation = ["Doctor", "Retired", "Police"].randomElement()!
        _ = PersistenceManager.init(entityType: Person.self).updateObject(object: self)
    }
    ///Predicate to filter out by age range
    static func ageRangePredicate(from: Int16, to: Int16) -> NSPredicate{
        NSPredicate(format: "age >= %d AND age <= %d", from, to)
    }
    ///Predicate to filter out by age
    static func agePredicate(age: Int16) -> NSPredicate{
        NSPredicate(format: "age == %d", age)
    }
    ///Predicate to filter out by occupation
    static func occupationPredicate(occupation: String, ascending: Bool = false) -> NSPredicate?{
        if occupation.isEmpty{
            return nil
        }else{
            return NSPredicate(format: "occupation CONTAINS %@", occupation)
        }
    }
    ///Compound predicate to filter by age range and occupation
    static func ageAndOccupationPredicate (ageFrom: Int16, ageTo: Int16, occupation: String) -> NSCompoundPredicate{
        
        let occPred = occupationPredicate(occupation: occupation)
        if occPred != nil{
            let pred = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [occPred!, ageRangePredicate(from: ageFrom, to: ageTo)])
            return pred
        }else{
            let pred = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [ageRangePredicate(from: ageFrom, to: ageTo)])
            return pred
        }
    }
}
```

This is what `Person` looks like in CoreData[image]

When you run the code it will look something like this. The sliders control the age and he picker the occupation

[image]